# Device (=keyboard) is sending ASCII (alt+number) to Android

Tags: android, keyboard, ascii

I have external bluetooth device, which is basically something like a keyboard.

But instead of letters and numbers this keyboard is sending data in ASCII.

- instead of "0" it will send "alt+48"
- instead of "M" it will send "alt+77"

And since Android doesn't have ALT he is is ignoring all received data (=ALT is pressed while receiving letters = I will ignore these letters).

Do you have any idea how to filter out pressed ALT? Or make Android accept send letters with pressed ALT?

Comment: Could you share detail about the device which you are using?

Comment: It's a RFID reader, which is emulating keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

override `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`

and use action `KeyAction.ACTION_DOWN` else you'll get duplicate data

and then set that add that character in your edit text

```
edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString+(char)

 @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int c = event.getUnicodeChar();

            if (IS_NEW_RF_ID) {
                rfIdAcTv.setText("");
            }

        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```